# Where to get feedback on homebrews

Tags: homebrew

I would like to post my homebrew subclass to get reliable feedback from the d&d 5e community. Do you have any suggestions as to what forums I should look to for that?

Comment: Ironically, the community-approved way to get that information is to incorrectly post a homebrew subclass.  If you're looking for "is this balanced", and you're willing to provide information on your goals, we can help you out.  If you are looking for a fuzzier response, we have a curated list of forums on the meta stack for you.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn how things work around here. This question will likely get closed as a shopping question, which are off-topic here. We have a [list of forums on meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/48759). You might also be interested in [How can I ask a good homebrew review question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8121/48759) for getting reviews here on the stack.

Comment: @linksassin This should probably be in an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @vicky_molokh I was wondering that myself and [asked it on meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8955/48759). I put it as a comment since I don't think we should be answering off-topic questions. However in general I agree with you.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I will redirect my question to the appropriate forum. In response to Ben, yes. I would like to see if it's balanced first and foremost. I would also be open to opinions on the general flavour of the brew. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This question will likely get closed as a shopping question, which are off-topic here. We have a [list of forums on meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/48759). You might also be interested in [How can I ask a good homebrew review question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8121/48759) for getting reviews here on the stack.